# Hide app icon and name from an android layout

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to develop an app(android:minSdkVersion=8, android:targetSdkVersion=19).I want to remove the app name and icon from the layout.I used this.

***android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"***

but it hide only the app name but not app icon..how is it possible?

Comment: <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"                   android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.elleys.MainActivity"
            android:label="ELLEYS">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: From your manifest i can see that you use AppTheme, not the one you mentioned in the question. Replace android:theme="@style/AppTheme" attribute with android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen".

Comment: Is it applicable for all API level?

Comment: Flags FLAG_FULLSCREEN and FEATURE_NO_TITLEFEATURE_NO_TITLE added in API 1.

Comment: But its getting exception:    Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Then the problem lays in something else. You should post all relevant code (especially when saying Exception) like activity, xml layout, manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Before setContentView on the pages:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```